# Jmockit in JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, jmockit

In a jboss service I need to mock some inner class (not EJB) with JMockit. Just for tests I've created inner class `ToBeMocked` and another one Mock. While deploying to jboss I get error `NoClassDefFoundError` in line:

```
Mockit.setUpMock(ToBeMocked.class, new Mock());
```

with message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mockit/Mockit
```

`jmockit.jar` is added to the classpath in `jboss_service.xml`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The "classpath" in jboss_service is very misleading in terms of jar location and how the attributes of the tag work. First, start by putting the Mockit jar in the server lib directory (if you didn't do anything fancy that is `server/default/lib` and restarting JBoss. If that works, then you can read more about how to correctly set that classpath attribute [here](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.3.0.cp08/html/Server_Configuration_Guide/Using_JMX_as_a_Microkernel-JBoss_MBean_Services.html) (search for the word `classpath`).